# GAE Getting Started with Flask (empty firefox browser)

Tags: html, python-2.7, google-app-engine, firefox, flask

I just went through the [Getting Start with Flask on App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env#test_the_application) tutorial. The source code is [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/flask/tutorial).

Firefox and Chrome both the html templates but neither render them when running locally:

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

or in the cloud

```
gcloud app deploy
```

The FireFox Developer Tools console tells me that:

> The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The
>   document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations
>   if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range.
>   The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or
>   in the transfer protocol.

I tried adding declaring UTF-8 encoding by adding this line to the html files.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    ...
```

but to no avail. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the URL path you tried ?

Comment: @Tuxdude I tried the following localhost: http://localhost:8080/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the reason your template is not rendering.  But, to get rid of that error, try:

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
```

To troubleshoot your template, please provide your url handlers, view handler, and template.html

Comment: # [START handlers]
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
# [END handlers]

Comment: I added the suggested meta content (getting same response as before)

Comment: I don't think there is a view handler, which sounds like it could be the problem. [source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/flask/tutorial)

Comment: Also no templates.html, but there is a [templates directory](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/flask/tutorial/templates).